# Проблема с названиями столбцов в DataGridView после привязки

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток.
Есть коллекция объектов собственного класса с открытыми свойствами. 
Есть также таблица dataGridView без столбцов.
Во время загрузки формы я свойству таблицы "DataSource" присваиваю объект bindingsource, DataSource которого, в свою очередь, ссылается уже на мою коллекцию (через дизайнер привязку сделать не могу, т.к. не могу выбрать сам объект) .
Результатом этого чуда есть то, что таблица добавляет столбцы таблицы с именем открытых свойств, и соответствующие значения каждого из объектов.
Но возникла проблема: имена столбцов должны называться не свойствами, а как я захочу. Как это сделать, используя привязку данных?

Comment: А атрибут [DisplayName("Имя")] привязать к открытым свойствам вашего объекта не пробовали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выставьте свойство [`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` в `false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и создайте нужные вам колонки вручную, проставляя у каждой из них `DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName` в имя соответствующей колонки из датасорса.

Или поменяйте свойство `Name` у автосгенерированных колонок.